# How to use jQuery validate for non-inputs or an alternative method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am attempting to add validation for a non-input, custom selection. I have a series of images that the user clicks, which act as a checkbox, but do not actually have an input. I am using jQuery validate for the rest of my form and wanted to see if there was anyway that I can add validation, whether it is adding a method (I read jQuery validate only works on inputs) or something else that will work with one click of submit.

I am wanting something similar to this, but to work like jQuery validate.

```
if(checkValue.length < 1) {
    alert("You need at least one interested selected.");
}
```

I tried putting the above if-statement above the rules section in the validation code, but it throws an error.

Does anyone have any alternative ideas that I could try?

```js
//Getting Value of the interest boxes
var interest = $('.interest');
var checkVal = '';
var checkValue = '';
interest.click(function() {
  checkVal = [];
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
  interest.each(function() {
   if($(this).is('.active')) {
    checkVal.push($(this).data('title'));
   }
  });
  checkValue = checkVal.join(', ');
  console.log(checkValue);
});

//Jquery Validate
$('#salesforce_submit').validate({
  rules: {
   first_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   }
  },
  messages: {
   first_name: {
    required: "Please enter your first name",
    minlength: "Your first name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var datastring = $('#salesforce_submit').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url: '/php/quoteSend.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datastring
    ,
    success: function(data) {
     if (data == 'Error!') {
      alert(data);
     } else {

     }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
     console.log('error');
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

```css
.interest img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="salesforce_submit" type="Post">
<div><input id="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="first_name" type="text"></div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">A</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="A">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="A">
</div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">B</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="B">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="B">
</div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">C</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="C">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="C">
</div>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Full code:

```
<section class="sec90">
            <h3 class="subTC">Enter your information below.</h3>
            <form action="" id="salesforce_submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="oid" type="hidden" value=""><input type="hidden" id="" id="interestValue" multiple="multiple" name="" value=""><input name="retURL" type="hidden"> <input name="lead_source" required="" type="hidden" value="Quote Form"> <input id="txt_medium" name="txt_medium" type="hidden" value=""> <input id="txt_source" name="txt_source" type="hidden" value=""> <input id="txt_campaign_name" name="txt_campaign_name" type="hidden" value=""> <input id="txt_term" name="txt_term" type="hidden" value=""> <input id="txt_content" name="txt_content" type="hidden" value="">
                <div><input id="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="first_name" type="text"></div>
                <div><input id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name*" class="input block" maxlength="80" name="last_name" type="text"></div>
                <div><input id="email" placeholder="Email*" class="input block" maxlength="80" name="email" type="email"></div>
                <div><input id="phone" placeholder="Phone* no dashes" class="input block" maxlength="12" name="phone" type="tel"></div>
                <div><input id="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code*" class="input block" maxlength="5" name="zip" type="text" pattern= "[0-9]{5}"></div>
                <div><input id="company" placeholder="Company*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="company" type="text"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="sec90">
                <h3 class="subTC">What are you interested in?*</h3>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="interestHidden" value=""></div>

        <section class="sec90" id="up">
                <h3 class="subTC">Describe your project*</h3>
                <div><textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Provide as much detail as possible"></textarea></div>
                <h3 class="subTC block">Have a .stp file or drawing example? Send it for quicker quote times.</h3>
                <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" class="inputfile" id="uploadedFile" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple>
                <label for="uploadedFile" class="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg><span class="marL5">Upload file</span></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
                <div class="margBot40"></div>
        </section>
                <input name="submit" class="block testB" type="submit" value="SUBMIT QUOTE">
            </form>
```

JS:

```
var interest = $('.interest');
    var checkVal = '';
    var checkValue = '';
    var showMe = '';

    interest.click(function() {
        checkVal = [];
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
        interest.each(function() {
            if($(this).is('.active')) {
                checkVal.push($(this).data('title'));
            }
        });
        checkValue = checkVal.join(', ');
        console.log(checkValue);
        //Hidden interest input value
        var checkLength = checkVal.length;
        console.log(checkLength);
        $('[name="interestHidden"]').val(checkLength);

        var interestVal = $('interestValue').val() 
        interestVal = checkValue;
        showMe = interestVal;
        console.log('Hidden val is ' + showMe); 
    });
    /*$('#phone').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3'));
    });*/
    $('#phone').keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        $text = $(this);
        if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
            if ($text.val().length === 3) {
                $text.val($text.val() + '-');
            }
            if ($text.val().length === 7) {
                $text.val($text.val() + '-');
            }
        }
        return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
    });

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
    {
        var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
            labelVal = label.innerHTML;

        input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
        {
            var fileName = '';
            if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
                fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
            else
                fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

            if( fileName )
                label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
            else
                label.innerHTML = labelVal;
        });
    });

    $('#phone').keyup(function() {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
            //return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
            return this.optional(element) || /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/i.test(value);
        }, "Numbers and dashes only");
    });

    $('#salesforce_submit').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                //digits: true,
                minlength: 10,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            zip: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            company: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            interestHidden: {
                required: true,
                min: 1
            }/*,
            description: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }*/
        },
        messages: {
            first_name: {
                required: "Please enter your first name",
                minlength: "Your first name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            last_name: {
                required: "Please enter your last name",
                minlength: "Your last name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                digits: "Please enter a valid phone number with only numbers",
                minlength: "Your number seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            zip: {
                required: "Please enter your zip code",
                digits: "Please enter a valid zip code with only numbers",
                minlength: "Your zip code seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            company: {
                required: "Please enter your company name",
                minlength: "Your company name seems a bit short. Please enter at least 2 characters"
            },
            interestHidden: {
                required: "Please choose at least one interest",
                min: "At least one interest needs chosen"
            }/*,
            description: {
                required: "Please enter your project description",
                minlength: "Your description seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            }*/
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var datastring = $('#salesforce_submit').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/php/quoteSend.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: datastring
                ,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 'Error!') {
                        alert('Unable to submit form!');
                        alert(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#salesforce_submit')[0].reset();
                        $('#consult-success').show();
                        $('#salesforce_submit').hide();
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {
                    //$("#salesforce_submit").submit();
                    location.href = "";
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery Validate only validates `select`, `textarea`, and various types of `input` elements<sup>1</sup>, your only option is to give it what it wants.

Create a hidden element...

```
<input type="hidden" name="myImage" value="0" />
```

When the user clicks your image, use jQuery to manipulate the value of a `type="hidden"` `input` element...

```
$('#photo').on('click', function() {
    $('[name="myImage"]').val('1');
});
```

And then programmatically validate its value instead.  Since clicking on the image will not cause any validation, you can use the `.valid()` method to trigger validation on these hidden elements...

```
$('[name="myImage"]').valid();
```

You will need to leverage the `ignore` option since the plugin will not validate hidden elements by default.  `ignore: []` will effectively disable this and force the plugin to validate all hidden elements...

```
$('#salesforce_submit').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: { ....
```

Of course, you'll also need to have rules in place that properly validate the value of your hidden element.

Since the message will be placed near the hidden element, you'll have to leverage the `errorPlacement` function to place this message conditionally.

```
$('#salesforce_submit').validate({
    ignore: [],
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') == 'myImage') {
            // placement for hidden element
        } else {
            // default
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
    rules: { ....
```

---

<sup>1</sup> newer versions of the plugin also support elements with the `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I incorporated all of this into my code, but for some reason the message is not showing up. I made a jsfiddle to test it and it works fine in this environment: https://jsfiddle.net/eqeLgL1n/4/ . I updated my question below with my full code. Do you see any reason why my message would not be showing?

Comment: I sort of figured out why the message wasn't showing. As you can see in my full code. I have the hidden field in a new section under the other inputs. When I put the hidden input right under the other inputs, the message shows up. Why would the message not show up in the new section? I added an image to show you that it shows up under the other inputs and where I was trying to get it.

Comment: You’ll have to create a new `errorPlacement` function to place that message conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

What about this, give all the checkboxes you trigger the same name e.g. "box".  Add this custom rule "img_check":

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("img_check", function() {
        $(input[name='box']).each( function(){
                     if $(this).is(':checked') {
                         return true
                     }
                })
                // No box was checked
                return false

}, "Please check at least one box");
```

Then add this rule:

```
rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        box[]: {
           img_check: true
           }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you check `checkValue` before going ahead with the submission process?

```js
//Getting Value of the interest boxes
var interest = $('.interest');
var checkVal = '';
var checkValue = '';
interest.click(function() {
  checkVal = [];
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.interestBox', this).toggleClass('active');
  interest.each(function() {
   if($(this).is('.active')) {
    checkVal.push($(this).data('title'));
   }
  });
  checkValue = checkVal.join(', ');
  console.log(checkValue);
});

//Jquery Validate

$('#salesforce_submit').validate({
  rules: {
   first_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   }
  },
  messages: {
   first_name: {
    required: "Please enter your first name",
    minlength: "Your first name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    if(checkValue.length>0){
   event.preventDefault();
   var datastring = $('#salesforce_submit').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url: '/php/quoteSend.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datastring
    ,
    success: function(data) {
     if (data == 'Error!') {
      alert(data);
     } else {

     }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
     console.log('error');
    }
   });
      }else console.log('Please select at least one interest');
  }
 });
```

```css
.interest img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="salesforce_submit" type="Post">
<div><input id="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="first_name" type="text"></div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">A</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="A">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="A">
</div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">B</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="B">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="B">
</div>
<h3 class="interestTitle">C</h3>
<div class="interest" data-title="C">
  <img src="https://www.mountaineers.org/images/placeholder-images/placeholder-400-x-400/image_preview" alt="C">
</div>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Will this run the jQuery validation at the same time?

Comment: @Paul since the if statement is inside the handler, it means all other *standard* validation will occur before this one, this one will only be checked when everything else has been checked, it will in no way hinder the rest of the validations